# How can I declare a Spring `depends-on` attribute with a bean ID that contains spaces?

Tags: spring

In Spring XML config I want to use the [`depends-on` attribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-dependson) to declare that a bean's initialization depends on another bean. The wrinkle is that I need to deal with bean IDs that contain spaces, like this:

```
<bean id="Bean A">
    <!-- stuff -->
</bean>

<bean id="Bean B" depends-on="Bean A">
    <!-- stuff -->
</bean>
```

Unfortunatley, that doesn't work because the `depends-on` attribute can accept a whitespace-separated list of bean IDs; Spring thinks it's looking for two beans for **Bean B** to depend on, **Bean** and **A**.

Is there any way to declare this such that it correctly resolves to **Bean A**?

*Note: comments or answers that simply say "don't use spaces in bean IDs" aren't useful; this question is not about the merit of that idiom/convention.*

Comment: Creating alias will help you in this situation. I am sure you are aware of the option. I don't see any other option.

Comment: @minion, that's not a bad idea. If you make it an answer I can accept it if nothing better is suggested.

Comment: done. Glad it was of help.

Comment: wondering if you found a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Documentation [depends-on](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-dependson) depends-on considers white space as one of the delimiters. This limits the beans having names or ids with spaces, one way to get around is to create alias for beans that has spaces in them and reference them in depends-on section.

```
<alias name="bean with space" alias="alias"/>
```

Comment: I was hoping for something else but this will get the job done in most of my cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

[5.4.3 Using depends-on](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-dependson)

> To express a dependency on multiple beans, supply a list of bean names as the value of the depends-on attribute, with commas, whitespace and semicolons, used as valid delimiters

That pretty much rules out bean IDs with spaces in them, unless there's some baroque and undocumented escaping syntax in the `depends-on` attribute.

There's advice I could give regarding the use of spaces in bean IDs and how they relate to bean names, but it seems you don't want to hear that,

Comment: I posted a different question specifically about using spaces in bean IDs, your thoughts and advice are welcome there. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125788/are-there-any-considerations-when-using-sprng-bean-ids-that-contain-spaces