# Are there any considerations when using Spring bean IDs that contain spaces?

Tags: java, spring, naming-conventions, spring-bean

Most examples of Spring bean IDs use Java-style variable names, such as `someBean`. However, that style isn't enforced; in fact, spaces and some other special characters are permitted (as of Spring 3.1 and later). An argument can be made for using more verbose bean IDs, such as:

```
<bean id="Some Bean" />
```

So far I've encountered only one issue with using bean IDs like that (see [How can I declare a Spring `depends-on` attribute with a bean ID that contains spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29109243/639520)). Are there any other important ramifications or limitations to consider when choosing bean names with spaces?

Comment: Note that an additional way to have Spring beans with spaces in their name would be to use Kotlin and configure through annotations, as Kotlin allows spaces in method names by enclosing them with backticks.